# Problems with the keyboard layout

Tags: language-support

I have the following problem: The distribution of my keyboard is Spanish (Latin America) however sometimes when I turn on my laptop the layout is English (US), even when in the keyboard setup says that im using Spanish. When I change it back to Spanish everything works fine. Someone knows how can I fix this?